# Translation of надкорневый

Tags: перевод

I can't seem to find a translation of this word into English. I've come across it in a language textbook, so I assume it's a word only a specialist in linguistics and/or anatomy would know. Based on the roots (no pun intended), I basically understand its meaning, but I'm looking for as exact a translation as possible. Perhaps there is no single word translation into English, in which case I'll simply substitute a phrase for it, but first I'd like to run it by you all before I make that decision. It was used in the context: "...язык продвигается вперед, надкорневая часть отходит назад, спинка языка выгибается кверху."

Comment: Just search for an English article about the articulation of the same sound. There is no need translating it word-to-word.

Comment: worth indicating to articulation of what sound specifically this description relates and providing more context

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian SE. Unfortunately, your question is off-topic here since it is actually about English, not Russian. That said, you can try your luck at English SE - however to make it on-topic there it still needs to be edited (the majority of English SE users need clarification what "надкорневый" is)

Comment: @Elena, please, avoid leaving answers that are essentially comments.

Comment: Better to ask questions like this in place that doesn't follow strict prison rules (like this site) Try Reddit :)

Comment: @VCH250 I'm not sure what you are talking about  - has one have asked "how to translate to Russian this English phrase" on English SE it would have been off-topic there. Do you disagree with this statement?

Comment: @shabunc the OP asks not only for translation but for a descriptive substitute as well which only native speakers can reliably provide

Comment: I repeat the same question I've asked VCH250 - in your opinion similar question but about translating into Russian - will it be on-topic on English SE?

Comment: It seems "надкорневая часть "is the same as "средняя часть спинки языка".